# 3/4 or 6/8?? Cliff Richard - Mistletoe and Wine

Tags: time-signatures

I hear this this song every Christmas on the radio (sorry I know its February now) and always count it in 6/8 - the snare to me is on the 2nd beat in 6/8 and the hi hat plays on every note of the bar (e.g. on the 123 456) - really can hear it on the verse.

I thought I'd check out the scores for it and most of them say 3/4 time - I'm thinking could I be that wrong, or why wouldn't they transcribe it in 6/8.

[Cliff Richard - Mistletoe and Wine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rZCEBibnRM8)

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer lies in these rhythms and the scansion...

[image]

..."-toe" being at the onset of the third eighth note value is clearly on a strong *beat* not the weak third eighth of of a compound dotted quarter beat.

[image]

..."-ti" is clearly a weak beat before a strong third beat. If it were 6/8 "-ti" would be the first eighth note on the down stroke of the dotted quarter note beat.

Of course you could divide all the values in half, change the meter to 6/8, slow the tempo way down, and then the stresses line up with beats.

On a purely mathematical basis those two options are equal.

But traditionally shorter note values connote faster rhythms. The 6/8 figures would look like a jig. Obviously that isn't right.

Also, there are a lot of single syllable words as quarter notes. The stress feels pretty strong on those words. Strong enough to be considered *beats* not *subdivisions.*

Answer (score 0):

Hearing two bars of 3/4 as one bar of 6/8 isn't THAT wrong!  Though my ears agree with the notation that it's 3/4.

It's 'one-in-a-bar'.  Akin (though not identical) to the Viennese waltz.
 You get the back-beat every second bar rather than every half bar. Where better for a strong beat than on One of a bar?

Comment: But it's clearly 2 beats per measure, no? Just at slow tempo. So 6/8 should be, at least  with only that criteria in mind, the more accurate one?

Comment: You can count it One-and-a-Two-and-a or you can count it One-two-three One-two-three. A slow 6/8 or a fast waltz.  I prefer the latter.  So no, I don't think it's clearly in 2.  But your opinion is valid.

Comment: When I say beats I don't mean the counting in my head, but the accents in the instrumentation, rhythm, melody, and harmony; how the piece was written and performed. It has a clear bias towards carving a 2 beats (accents, kick, snare, etc.) per measure idea. You can count it in 3/4 without issues, but the beats will not align with the accents that are happening in the music.

Comment: Keith Strachan originally wrote it for his child's school Nativity play.  I'll actually be passing his house later today!  Shall I pop in and tell him he notated it wrong?

Comment: @LaurencePayne - Wait, you've accessed a score of this piece that was from his manuscripts and not a transcription by a third party?